# Office 2010 - Binding XML to picture content control causes error when resized

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

Hell all,

I creating Word 2010 documents that will have content controls that I will bind XML to. I am using the [Word Content Control Toolkit](http://dbe.codeplex.com/) to help facilitate this.

I have run into an issue with a picture content control. If I create the control then open the document with the content control toolkit and add create an xml part with the following simple XML:

```
<root>
   <pic></pic>
</root>
```

Then use the toolkit to bind the pic node to my picture control. If I open the document it looks ok. **However** if I resize the image control, save the document and reopen it I get the following error:
"The file filename.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents. I get the option to try and recover the file but doing so results in the image being moved a bit(seemingly random) and even if I saved the recovered file I will continue to get that error every time I open it.

Could anyone suggest what could be going wrong here? I have done this type of stuff before and didn't have an issue. Any help or advice would be very much appreciated, thanks!